# Finding full text of fare rules if I have the fare basis code

Tags: tickets, airlines, fares

If I know the name of an airline and the exact fare basis code, where can I look up the full text of the fare rules? (I'm looking for things like change fees, restrictions on changes, refundability of the ticket, etc).

Specifically, right now I'm looking for fare rules for TransAero's TLEE4M and VLEE6M fares. I've tried the obvious things like looking at TransAero's website (both in English and in Russian), Googling the codes and various prefixes of the codes, etc., but couldn't find anything. Is there a service where I can just plug in the airline code and the fare basis code and it will show me the rules?

Comment: There are a bazillion different combos and airlines change the coding of fare basis from time to time.  It would be a nightmare to keep that database up to date.

Comment: Well, the GDSes / travel-agent interfaces must have this info, so I'm pretty sure a database exists, I'm just wondering if it's accessible to a mere mortal like me somewhere : )

Comment: Yes each airline's database has this data and the GDS usually has the ability to search that data, but I am unaware of a single database that has it all.  You could do a trial booking and read the rules there.

Comment: Can you get the same fare to show up on a search on the [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/)? If so, if you click into enough details pages you'll get to the full fare rules

Comment: I had the same problem with Lufthansa recently and couldn't really get any decent information. The only hint I got was that when calculating the miles you're supposed to get, use the first letter of the fare class (VLEE6M -> V) when checking out the details.

Comment: No clue why the question got closed here. I asked it on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/84825/903 since I wondered the same.